# jQuery getJSON Output using Python/Django

Tags: python, django-views, jsonp, getjson

So, I'm trying to make a simple call using jQuery .getJSON to my local web server using python/django to serve up its requests.  The address being used is:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/0.1/tonight-mobile.json?callback=jsonp1290277462296
```

I'm trying to write a simple web view that can access this url and return a JSON packet as the result (worried about actual element values/layout later).

Here's my simple attempt at just alerting/returning the data:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/0.1/tonight-mobile.json&callback=?",
function(json){
    alert(json);
    <!--$.each(json.items, function(i,item){
    });-->
});
```

I am able to access this URL directly, either at http://localhost:8000/api/0.1/tonight-mobile.json or http://localhost:8000/api/0.1/tonight-mobile.json&callback=jsonp1290277462296 and **get back a valid JSON packet...** So I'm assuming it's in my noob javascript:)

My views.py function that is generating this response looks as follows:

```
def tonight_mobile(request):
    callback = request.GET.get('callback=?', '')    

    def with_rank(rank, place):
        return (rank > 0)

    place_data = dict(
        Places = [make_mobile_place_dict(request, p) for p in Place.objects.all()]
    )

    xml_bytes = json.dumps(place_data)
    xml_bytes = callback + '(' + xml_bytes + ');'

    return HttpResponse(xml_bytes, mimetype="application/json")
```

With corresponding urls.py configuration:

```
(r'^tonight-mobile.json','iphone_api.views.tonight_mobile'),
```

***I am still somewhat confused on how to use callbacks, so maybe that is where my issue lies.  Note I am able to call directly a 'blah.json' file that is giving me a response, but not through a wired URL.  Could someone assist me with some direction?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `callback = request.GET.get('callback=?', '')` won't get you the value of `callback`.

```
callback = request.GET.get( 'callback', None )
```

Works much better.

To debug this kind of thing.  You might want to include `print` statements in your Django view function so you can see what's going on.  For example: `print repr(request.GET)` is a helpful thing to put in a view function so that you can see the GET dictionary.

Comment: S.Lott, thank you for the response.  However, your answer does not seem to give me any sort of result - just a error in my view stating:
'QueryDict' object is not callable..

Comment: @user546459: I made a change.  You can do "debugguing", you know.  You try different things.  Add `print` statements.  Experiment.  It's allowed, you know.